# Error in SQL Syntax with tmp table subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, amazon-rds

I have a query as follows:

```
WITH tmp_table as 
  (SELECT (ft_team_1_goals + ft_team_2_goals) as total 
    from results where ((player_1='fric' or player_2='fric') 
                        AND ft_team_1_goals is not null 
                        AND (la_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-04-20'))
  ) 
  select count(*) from tmp_table where total<=2
```

This is giving me an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

I cannot see anything wrong with it.

I recently migrated to Amazon Aurora MySQL instance. Before that on my localhost mariadb, this query was fine.

Can you see whats wrong with it?

Comment: Without the complete error message it's hard to say but I suspect you've migrated to a version of MySQL that doesn't support CTEs i.e. 5.7 or below

Comment: While it's good that you included the error message, it's more helpful if you include the entire message. You've left out some of the necessary information from that message.